# Installing nokogiri after a Mavericks upgrade -- entities.c is missing?

Tags: nokogiri, osx-mavericks

I'm running into the same problem most people are running into with nokogiri install on post-Mavericks upgrade machine.

```
    /Users/lunchbag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libx/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/lunchbag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby
/Users/lunchbag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.3/lib/mini_portile.rb:278:in `block in execute': Failed to complete configure task (RuntimeError)
from /Users/lunchbag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.3/lib/mini_portile.rb:270:in `chdir'
from /Users/lunchbag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.3/lib/mini_portile.rb:270:in `execute'
from /Users/lunchbag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.3/lib/mini_portile.rb:65:in `configure'
from /Users/lunchbag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.3/lib/mini_portile.rb:108:in `cook'
from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lunchbag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/lunchbag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.1/gem_make.out
```

My configure.log shows the following error:

```
configure: error: cannot find sources (entities.c) in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm or ..
```

I've tried installing/reinstalling/unlinking/relinking libxml2, libxslt.

Any other tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Installing the libraries with Homebrew and setting `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1` before installing the gem did the trick for me.

Summarising:

- If previously installed, uninstall the gem:
  `$ gem uninstall nokogiri`
- Use Homebrew to install `libxml2`, `libxslt` and `libiconv`:
  `$ brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv`
- Install the gem specifying the paths to the libraries to be linked against:
  `$ NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir="$(brew --prefix libiconv)" --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config" --with-xslt-config="$(brew --prefix libxslt)/bin/xslt-config"`

Comment: I had to do `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv`

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem. I latched onto why is it looking for (entities.c) in

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm or ..
```

I'm no expert but npm probably doesn't have make files in it.

I got nokogiri to install by removing npm from my ~/.bash_profile (the other place to check might be ~/.profile). Here was how my .bash_profile looked:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi

source ~/.profile
```

You can see npm in the first line, I just deleted that, reloaded my terminal (so it stopped looking in npm directory for stuff) and did sudo gem install nokogiri AND IT WORKED :)!!!

As a side note npm commands seem to be working so I don't know why I had that path in my .bash_profile

Hope this helps, first answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for Yosemite and libxml2 installed via brew

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.5' -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2
```